# Not able to create a folder/file in Android file system with PCLStorage or Xamarin Forms Labs

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

Im developing an Android app using the Xamarin platform and Im trying to create a folder on my local storage but I have had no success.

First I tried using the System.IO namespace through a FileManager class created by Xamarin Forms Labs. A snippet of the functions I was passing the path of "/storage/emulated/0/`".

```
        public void CreateDirectory(string path)
        {
            this.isolatedStorageFile.CreateDirectory(path);
        }

        public Stream OpenFile(string path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access)
        {
            return (Stream)this.isolatedStorageFile.OpenFile(path, (System.IO.FileMode)mode, (System.IO.FileAccess)access);
        }
```

This didn't work so I then opted to using PCLStorage a library for cross platform file operations. I tried this code.

```
IFolder rootFolder = FileSystem.Current.LocalStorage;
folder = await rootFolder.CreateFolderAsync("wakesocial",
                CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
```

Didn't work. I navigated to the root of the internal storage and I didn't see the folder.

So the error doesn't seem to be occurring because of the libraries in use but something specific to Android. I  have read and write to external storage in manifest. So the question is. Does an app have permission to create a file or folder at the root level of the storage device or does it have to create it at particular location such as in Android/data/packagename

Comment: Providing you have the read/write permissions set in your manifest, there shouldn't be any reason why you can't create a directory or file in the root sdcard path. What path are you providing to `CreateDirectory()`? EG: Are you using one of the System.Environment.SpecialFolder folder types?

Comment: Also, what data type is `isolatedStorageFile`?

Comment: @MattR System.IO.IsolatedStorage

Comment: Ah yeah, I missed the PCL component of your question. `System.Environment.SpecialFolder` isn't available in a PCL.

Comment: OK I removed that because I know its not available. i am gonna set it in a variable in a android app then use that path and see if it works.

Comment: Hmm, `isolatedStorageFile.CreateDirectory()` doesn't seem to create a folder for me either. Can you use `Directory.Create()` as an alternative?

Comment: hmmmmm directory.create() works.

Comment: Would please post your changes? I am facing a similar issue.

Comment: Hey I moved on from the platform and went back to Native Android. So best you create an issue on GitHub.

Answer (score 4):

```
string folderPath = Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath; //Android     

   public async Task PCLGenaratePdf(string folderPath )
    {
        IFolder rootFolder = await FileSystem.Current.GetFolderFromPathAsync(folderPath );
        IFolder folder = await rootFolder.CreateFolderAsync("folder", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
        IFile file = await folder.CreateFileAsync("file.pdf", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply Iceburg, i try it once again and let you know. And if it is working it is not selected as answer?

Comment: What namespace is required for adding IFolder in my happy.xaml.cs ?

Comment: @AshishJain add PCL Storage nuget package

Comment: Can you please let me know exactly the name of that nugget package? it will be really helpful.

Comment: It is working, I made a mistake at some point, now it's working, one more thing I need to ask what is the path you are passing? is it the folder path? if yes then how you are getting the folder path? this line is not working for me to getting path

string path = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);

Comment: see the modified answer

Answer (score 2):

After lot of trying I solved this problem with this

```
        string rootPath = Android.App.Application.Context.GetExternalFilesDir(null).ToString();

        var filePathDir = Path.Combine(rootPath, "Folder");

        if (!File.Exists(filePathDir))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(filePathDir);
        }
```

The folder created is reachable through adb @ /sdcard/Android/Data/Folder or something like this, or in device memory @ /Android/data/<< AppName >>/files/Folder

Answer (score 1):

On Android, PCL Storage's LocalStorage folder [corresponds to the "My Documents" Special Folder](https://github.com/dsplaisted/PCLStorage/blob/d1b905429d0686ed8dfdf03c26fe83ea3c5857ce/src/PCLStorage.FileSystem.Desktop/DesktopFileSystem.cs#L26).

I'm not sure exactly what path you're trying to create a folder in, but if you know the path and want to use PCL Storage, you should be able to use `FileSystem.Current.GetFolderFromPathAsync` to get a PCL Storage `IFolder` corresponding to an existing folder.